# Drupal 7 - Integrate the color module into my custom module

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I know how to intergrate the color module into my theme so I can manage site colors from the apearence page but I want to add it to my custom module instead.

Is it possible to integrate the color module into a custom module? I can't find any documentation on this.

Any advise would be great.

Comment: That's a good question. It would be a great advantage if we know how to do this.